# Issuer giving duplicate verify credential each time, not sure why

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-verifiable-credentials

We are creating a POC with Azure verifiable credentials, we have build an issuer and verifier application and for holder we are using Microsoft Authenticator app. When we scan the QR code from issuer page and try to add card in the wallet then it is adding a new card each time when we scan a generated QR code.

So can anybody please confirm, if is it correct flow, then how to manage only one card for one holder  from one issuer?

Attaching the screenshots of my mobile, showing cards in my wallet:

[image: Showing all the cards in my wallet]

**First Card with claim details**

[image]

**Last card with same claim details**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. You get multiple VCs if you repeat the issuance process. It is up to the business rule of relying party app for issuance to allow/deny this.